# How to create directory if needed?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use makefile, my problem is that I have a directory, with an `src` directory and a `Makefile`. I also use a `tmp` directory what I also have to create.
It has object files in it. And for performance, I try not to delete these when debugging.
If I create a rule for tmp to create it, it always rebuilds all the C files.
So how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create directories using make file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a number of ways.  It depends on what version of `make` you're using and what operating system you're using.

The one thing you must NEVER do is use a directory as a simple prerequisite.  The rules the filesystem uses to update the modified time on directories do not work well with `make`.

For simple `make` on a POSIX system, you can pre-create the directory in the rule to perform the compilation:

```
obj/foo.o: foo.c
        @ mdkir -p obj
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

If you have GNU make you have two options.  The simplest one is simply to force the directory to be created when the makefile is read in before anything else happens, by adding a line like this:

```
_dummy := $(shell mkdir -p obj)
```

The is easy, fast, and reliable.  Its only downside is that the directory will be created always, even if it's not needed.  Nevertheless this is the way I usually do it.

The most fancy way, if you have a new-enough GNU make, is to use order-only prerequisites:

```
obj/foo.o: foo.c | obj
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

obj:
        mkdir -p $@
```

This forces the `obj` target to be built before the `obj/foo.o` target, *but* the timestamp on `obj` is ignored when determining whether `obj/foo.o` is out of date.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without GNU make extensions? (The question is tagged `Makefile`, not `GNUmakefile`).

Comment: No, there is no way to use a directory as a prerequisite (such that it behaves as desired) when writing POSIX-compliant makefiles.  The only thing you can do is rewrite all your rules to add in an explicit `mkdir -p` before they attempt to use a directory that might not exist, and not use prerequisites or make rules to build the directory.

Comment: You do not even need the `_dummy`.
The line `$(shell mkdir -p obj)` is enough

Comment: Probably not absolutely required in this specific situation but the `_dummy` is there in case the code run by `$(shell ...)` prints any output to stdout.  If that were to happen then you'd get a syntax error in your makefile.  `mkdir` doesn't print to stdout normally of course.