# Make and last modification times of directories on Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following makefile:

```
foo :
    mkdir foo

foo/a.out : foo a.in
    cp a.in foo/a.out

foo/b.out : foo b.in
    cp b.in foo/b.out
```

and the following interaction with it, starting from a directory that contains files `a.in` and `b.in` and nothing else:

```
$ make foo/a.out
mkdir foo
cp a.in foo/a.out
```

So far, so good.

```
$ make foo/b.out
cp b.in foo/b.out
```

Still good, but now:

```
$ make foo/a.out   # a.out should be up to date now!
cp a.in foo/a.out
```

It rebuilds the `a.out` target, even though none of its prerequisites have changed.

It seems like what's happening is that when `foo/b.out` is created, the last modification time of the directory `foo` is updated, so it picks that up as having "changed".

Is there a way to avoid this? For example, is there a way to declare that `foo/a.out` depends on `foo` only in that `foo` has to exist, and the creating of files inside `foo` doesn't cause `foo` to be considered out of date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As an authority on Make recently pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344719/how-to-create-directory-if-needed/16346321#16346321):

*"The one thing you must NEVER do is use a directory as a simple prerequisite. The rules the filesystem uses to update the modified time on directories do not work well with make."*

But I think this will do what you want:

```
foo :
    mkdir foo

foo/a.out : a.in | foo
    cp a.in foo/a.out

foo/b.out : b.in | foo
    cp b.in foo/b.out
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about this feature, but note that it's only available in newish versions of GNU Make.

Comment: Err... for some definition of "newish" I guess.  Order-only prerequisites were added in GNU make 3.80 which was released over 10 years ago, in Oct 2002.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Beta's answer, but it is not portable. For a simple portable workaround, create a sentinel file when you create the directory, and depend on the sentinel file instead.

```
foo/.dir:
        mkdir -p foo
        touch $@
foo/a.out: a.in foo/.dir
        cp $< $@
foo/b.out: b.in foo/.dir
        cp $< $@
```

This can be further simplified with a pattern rule:

```
foo/%.out: %.in foo/.dir
        cp $< $@
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the targets dependent on the directory, you can simply create the directory unconditionally in their build rules:

```
foo/a.out: a.in
        mkdir -p foo
        cp a.in foo/a.out

foo/b.out: b.in
        mkdir -p foo
        cp b.in foo/b.out
```

This avoids problems with using a directory as a prerequisite.

Comment: @HighCommander4 True, although in practice I'd expect to use a pattern-based rule for this rather than individual rules for each target. I'd recommend the other answer if your version of make supports it. See also the question that Beta linked to, which has some more discussion of this issue.

Comment: Consider the slightly modified scenario where the `.in` files are also in `foo`, and there is another directory `bar` similar to `foo`. Say my pattern-based rule is `%.out : %.in` (with the actions omitted), and then I have rules `foo/% : foo` and `bar/% : bar` with no actions to get the directory prerequisites in place. What do I `mkdir` in the body of the `%.out : %.in` rule?

Comment: @HighCommander4 I'm having a hard time picturing this. How do the `%.in` files exist if the directory doesn't?

Comment: You're right, that made no sense :) Let me try again, with a real example this time. Say I have a rule for making any object file, of the form `%.o : `  (and then the action). I don't put any prerequisites here. Then I have rules with no actions of the form `foo/cat.o : src/cat.c foo` and `bar/dog.o : src/dog.c bar`. If I put the `mkdir` action into these rules, they'll be run instead of the `%.o` rule rather than just adding prerequisites to it. But if I try to put the `mkdir` into the `%.o` rule, what do I `mkdir`?

Comment: @HighCommander4, you should _always_ `mkdir -p $(@D)`.  The `$(@D)` automatic variable gives the directory of the target (`$@`).  Use the `-p` option so it won't fail if the directory already exists.