# Create Directory using MakeFile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a MakeFile, but I need it to create folder OBJ, so, for this, I tried a lot of things... based on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

So, that is my makefile

```
IDIR =.
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -Wall -g

SRCDIR=src
ODIR=obj
LIBS=-ltest

_OBJ = main.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

OUTPUTDIR = ../bin

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OUTPUTDIR)/test: $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

I need to create the obj folder, I tried that idea:

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

and this:

```
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

.PHONY: directories

all: directories program

directories: ${OUT_DIR}

${OUT_DIR}:
        ${MKDIR_P} ${OUT_DIR}
```

But apparently every time I called the makefile, it ignored the command to create the directory OBJ and began compiling directly...

How I can make to makefile create the directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create directory if needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344719/how-to-create-directory-if-needed)

Comment: It really isn't clear why the [Ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page is a helpful link.

Comment: The last fragment would work if you define `OUT_DIR = ${ODIR}` or to some other suitable value.  The pipe symbol in the middle fragment is puzzling; I don't think I've seen that notation before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The pipe indicates that `$(OBJDIR)` is an ["order-only" prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types), so that it will be rebuilt if the target is rebuilt, but the target need not be rebuilt just because this prereq needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create directories using make file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to have a dummy variable that evaluates early in the parse of the Makefile and produces the required folder.

```
   ODIR = obj_64
   dummy_build_folder := $(shell mkdir -p $(ODIR))
```

Then the rest of the Makefile can safely assume that $(ODIR) exists.

I've used this on various Linux flavors, and Solaris, with GNU Make 3.81.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR): FORCE
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

FORCE:
```