# save file into a new folder makefile

Tags: c, makefile, directory, mkdir

I have started learning how to create makefiles and met some problems.. I don't understand how to save a compiled file into a new folder (which I create with the makefile)..

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -ansi
FILE=main.c func.c

default: compile


compile: $(FILE) header.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o prova $(FILE)

clean: 
    $(RM) count *.o *~
```

I don't know how to continue. I've searched online but all sources seems complicate.

Comment: A makefile is kinda like a recipe to doing things in the shell. How would you do it by hand? `mkdir foo`? You can have rule that does just that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create directory if needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344719/how-to-create-directory-if-needed) or [Create directories using make file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file)

Comment: i asked how to create a new folder AND save the new compiled files into that new folder.