# How to change my makefile to build into a separate folder

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=g++
CCOPTS=-Wall -Wextra -g

OBJS = manager.o tcpcon.o
TARGETS = manager

.PHONY: all clean

$(TARGETS) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

all: $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)

%: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCOPTS) -o $@ $<
```

Is there a way I can make my .o and bin files be built into a directory called `build`? I tried going through some tutorials, but I guess I just don't fully understand makefiles..

Comment: I believe that this should be helpful:

[Click on this Link to a Similar Question answered in 2009 on Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't feel too bad; I'm not sure *anyone* fully understands makefiles.

```
BUILD_DIR = build

OBJS = $(BUILD_DIR)/manager.o $(BUILD_DIR)/tcpcon.o
TARGETS = $(BUILD_DIR)/manager

...

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CCOPTS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Hm, now I get the following: make: *** No rule to make target `build/manager.o', needed by `build/manager'.  Stop. .... I've updated my original question with what I have now.

Comment: @ctote: Sorry, there was a flaw in my answer, now corrected. But please don't "update" your question like that; it makes the answer obsolete and destroys the value of the question for other users.