# can't compile using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have some opencv c++ code on ubuntu whose folder structure is:

```
|-- bin
|   |-- camera-calib.o
|   `-- frontalize.o
|-- docs
|   `-- notes.md
|-- LICENSE.md
|-- Makefile
|-- README.md
|-- shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
`-- src
    |-- calib
    |   |-- calib.cpp
    |   |-- calib.h
    |   |-- POSIT.cpp
    |   |-- POSIT.h
    |   |-- pro
    |   |   |-- calib.o
    |   |   |-- Makefile
    |   |   |-- POSIT.o
    |   |   |-- pro
    |   |   |-- pro.pro
    |   |   |-- pro.pro~
    |   |   `-- util.o
    |   `-- util
    |       |-- calib_util.cpp
    |       `-- calib_util.h
    |-- camera-calib.cpp
    |-- camera-calib.h
    |-- check_resources.h
    |-- fatialfeaturedetect.cpp
    |-- frontalization-models
    |   |-- DataAlign2LFWa.mat
    |   |-- eyemask.mat
    |   `-- model3Ddlib.mat
    |-- frontalize.cpp
    |-- frontalize.h
    `-- main.cpp
```

The Makefile I am using is:

```
EXE = face_frontalization
OBJ_DIR = bin
CFLAGS = -g -w

dummy_build_folder := $(shell mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR))

 # c++ source files of the project
CXXFILES = $(shell find src -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*.cpp')
CXXOBJ = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,bin/%.o,$(CXXFILES))

INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/dlib-18.18
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
CXXFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -w -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++0x
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -g -w

ifdef V
MUTE =
VTAG = -v
else
MUTE = @
endif

all: $(EXE)
    # build successful

$(EXE): $(CXXOBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXOBJ) -o $(EXE) $(LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@
    $(BUILD)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@

run: all
    ./$(EXE)

clean:
    # Cleaning...
    -rm -f $(EXE) $(CXXOBJ)
    rmdir bin/
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
6 of 7
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -w -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/dlib-18.18 src/calib/util/calib_util.cpp -c -o bin/calib/util/calib_util.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create bin/calib/util/calib_util.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [bin/calib/util/calib_util.o] Error 1
```

I haven't got this error before so don't know why its coming up. The file is present in the directory. What should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your directory structure is a little off.

> can't create bin/calib/util/calib_util.o: No such file or directory

According to your hierarchy, you don't have the directories `calib/util` under `bin`. Try creating that and run `make` again.

Comment: Can I put some code in Makefile to do that for me automatically by just seeing the src folder structure?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file).

Comment: just 1 more ques. Is it a good way to use this line :CXXFILES = $(shell find src -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*.cpp')
or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @leehuang I don't see why not. I wouldn't suggest modifying their Makefile. They wrote it like it is for a reason. Do you see a problem with it?

Comment: Its my own makefile. That's why I am asking :). I mean if I add more code with more nested dirs than 3 I will have to modify again. If I want to make it more robust is there a way?

Comment: @leehuang Ahh, my mistake. I thought you were compiling opencv. Yes, that's a good point. What if you don't tell it to search to a max depth (remove that flag)?

Comment: Then it doesn't go into the dir. Just compiles the outermost files in the src folder and thats that

Comment: @leehuang that's strange. It should descend by default. I just checked, and I had no problems. Could you run that command in the shell and see if it returns the files?

Comment: Tried that again by cleaning everything up. It works now. Thanks a lot for the help:)