# Conditional statements using Make

Tags: makefile

I'm having a problem with conditional statements in make.  Existing questions on SO only work on the highest level in the Makefile.

Here's what I have:

```
.PHONY: all

all: bar/*.o

bar/%.o: foo/%.cc
ifeq (,$(wildcard $(@D)))
    @echo $(wildcard $(@D))
endif
```

There are two empty files under `foo`, `a.cc` and `b.cc`.  The folder `bar` exists.

Here's the output:

```
PS C:\Users\cbrown2\Src> mingw32-make
bar
bar
```

It enters the `ifeq` statement, even though `$(wildcard $(@D))` gives `bar`.

What gives?

Comment: Can you just do `@mkdir -p (@D)` unconditionally?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file

Comment: `@mkdir -p` makes a directory called `-p`

Comment: I am currently trying to work around this exact thing.  There are a bunch of `@mkdir -p` commands in a package I am compiling, and they all fail.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mingw32, but on *nix `mkdir -p x/y/z` creates parents directories as necessary.

Comment: If indeed `-p` isn't supported in your env, then I'd suggest that you probably still want to solve the issue at the shell level (i.e. the recipe inside the rule), rather than the Makefile level.

Comment: Solving at the Makefile level should be system independent, is why I wanted such a solution.

Comment: Furthermore, my specific use case is for `mkdir`, but the problem is actually with the `ifeq`, `wildcard` statement.  I will update to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use conditionals this way. When make evaluates your conditional automatic variables don't have a value yet. So make will see:

```
bar/%.o: foo/%.cc
    @echo $(wildcard $(@D))
```

because `$(@D)` expands as the empty string. And when make will pass the recipe to the shell it will first expand `$(@D)` which, this time, has a value: `bar`.

One side note that has nothing to do with your problem: when `bar` does not contain all object files yet,

```
all: bar/*.o
```

will not do what you probably want. What you probably want is:

```
SRC := $(wildcard foo/*.cc)
OBJ := $(patsubst foo/%.cc,bar/%.o,$(SRC))

all: $(OBJ)
```