# Makefile cannot create directories

Tags: makefile

I'm creating a makefile to compile a project I have, and I want it to create the /obj and /bin directories by itself.

My first attempt was trying to treat the directories as a target, but that didn't work. Now I followed the steps explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file), and I got this error;

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'bin/main.out'. Stop.
```

This is my makefile:

```
bin = ./bin/
src = ./src/
obj = ./obj/

CXX = g++
CCFLAGS = -Wall -g -c
CXXFLAGS = -O3

HDRS = $(src)ShallowWater.h
OBJS = $(obj)main.o $(obj)TimeIntegrate.o $(obj)derivatives.o $(obj)SetInitialConditions.o $(obj)SetBoundaryConditions.o $(obj)SetParameters.o
LIBS = -lblas -lboost_program_options -fopenmp

$(bin)main.out: $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(obj)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

$(obj)%.o: $(src)%.cpp $(HDRS)
    @mkdir -p $(obj)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

I think it must have something to do with the fact that if the directory does not already exist it treats obj/main.o as a file name, not as a file path.

Comment: Your guess is not right (most likely--please provide information on what version of GNU make you're using).  To know what the problem is, run `make -d` and follow the output to figure out why make decides that your pattern rule isn't good enough.  Usually it means that either `src/main.cpp` or `src/ShallowWater.h` doesn't exist, so that pattern rule doesn't match.

Comment: I'm using GNU 4.3. The two files in source do exist and the makefile runs if I manually create the bin and obj directories.

Comment: "*My first attempt was trying to treat the directories as a target, but that didn't work.*" -- dunno what you actually did, but it can totally work to use directory names as targets, together with a recipe for creating those directories.  And that's what the makefile example you linked to is doing, btw.

Comment: My first guess would be that `src/main.cpp` does not exist, as resolved relative to the working directory from which you run `make`.  Or perhaps that `src/ShallowWater.h` doesn't.

Comment: Style recommendation: do not end the values of your directory variables with a slash (`/`).  Putting literal slashes in your source and prerequisite names is a lot clearer.  For example, `$(obj)/main.o`.  This is not related to your error, however, unless by something you haven't shown us.

Comment: As I said in my first message, what you're doing definitely works.  I tried it myself with the makefile you provided.  That means something is different in your environment than you've explained to us here.  So to find out what the problem is you should run `make -d` and examine the output: make will tell you why it decided that the recipe that you gave didn't match.