# GNU Make, replicating source code structure in a _build folder

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a setup like the following one (using GNU Make 4.2.1):

```
Makefile
main.cpp
subfolder/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
    etc...
```

I want to compile all of those .cpp into their corresponding .o in _build but preserving the directory structure, so that after compilation I have:

```
Makefile
_build
   final_binary
   main.o
   subfolder/
      a.o
      b.o
main.cpp
   subfolder/
      a.cpp
      b.cpp
```

I haven't been able to make this work properly. My makefile is something like:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,_build/%.o,main.cpp $(wildcard subfolder/*.cpp))
TARGET := _build/final_binary
DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(OBJS) $(TARGET)))

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@ $(LDPATHS)

$(OBJS) $(TARGET): %: | $(dir %)
_build/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

But I can't make it work, and the problem seems related to the surprising fact that `%` is not a regular wildcard that consumes everything against the matching target, but that removes directories and then paste the steams in very unintuitive ways, and I'm having trouble at every attempt. Another approach I tried was:

```
### $(OBJS) $(TARGET): %: | $(dir %)
_build/%.o: %.cpp | $(dir _build/%.o)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

but that's just me improvising honestly. The deal with `%` ignoring directories makes me not fully trust anything that contains a `%`.

What is the proper way to create the required folders by demand? (and by demand I mean, not writing any order-only prerequisite for $(TARGET) that creates all folders at once, but creating only the subfolders that are required for a particular `.o`).

If it's worth generalizing the question at this point, this problem is really an instance of the general problem of doing cross-folder pattern matching in GNU Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with how patterns match directories.

The problem is that expansion of prerequisites happens *immediately* when the rule is parsed, but expansion of patterns happens later.  So when you write `% : | $(dir %)` you are not running `dir` on the thing that the pattern expands to, you are running on the literal value `%` and the `dir` of a word with no `/` is always `./`.  So you are writing `% : | ./`.

Similarly in your pattern rule: `_build/%.o: %.cpp | $(dir _build/%.o)` here the `$(dir ..)` is expanded when the pattern rule is parsed and so you are writing `_build/%.o: %.cpp | _build/` which is not what you want.

I really don't see any point in this complexity: the `mkdir` solution is by far the simplest and doesn't require any specialized make features, and the build time difference cannot be measured in my opinion.

But if you do want to do this you'll have to make use of even MORE specialized make features, you'll need to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
_build/%.o: %.cpp | $$(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

(note the extra `$`).

Answer (score 1):

You can just have your build rules create the directory ad-hoc:

```
_build/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I prefer not to add that extra command whenever I build a file if the folder already exists. I want `make` to know what's missing and be minimalistic on the amount of commands to execute. Think that calling mkdir is forking another extra process per-file when 99% of them don't really need it (because each mkdir satisfy the dependences of a lot of files).

Comment: On the other hand I could create a target that is execute before any compilation rule that creates all folders at once, but I want to know at this point what is the "right way" to do it. After all, this is really a question about doing cross-folder pattern matching, not really about what you plan to do per-match.

Comment: There is a good discussion on various approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file)

Comment: That discussion is pretty old.  personally I don't think much of most of those solutions.  But YMMV.